# Smooth scrolling on a Kindle Fire

Tags: scroll, kindle-fire, amazon-silk

I've created a simple example page which shows my problem: http://jsbin.com/owivak/1/

Scrolling this page in a browser works fine on most platforms, the lovely green header bar stays where it is and the other content scrolls behind it as it should, it's a fixed header.

The problem I'm having is with the Amazon Silk browser on the Kindle Fire. I realise this is a fairly low powered device, but it's not too low powered to be able scroll this incredibly simple page... except it is!

The problem is that on the Kindle Fire in its Silk browser the header appears to be being redrawn as you scroll and looks incredibly glitchy.

Has anyone ever come across this or a similar problem? And any suggestions on how to solve?

Comment: how well does this work in other Android 4.0 devices (or Nexus7). Acceleration doesn't seem to make a difference so it may be down to perf :(

Comment: Fine on other Andriod 4. I realise performance may be an issue, but with this incredibly simple example there is almost nothing happening! And the Kindle Fire will display other far more heavy websites without problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this was a bug in the Kindle Fire Silk Browser. Updating to the latest software (10.3 at time of writing) solves the issue.

Comment: FWIW it looks like the fix rolled out to the HD devices as well - your sample looks good there as well